# How to query JPA @ElementCollection map properties

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I use JPA (hibernate 5.4.30.Final) to store entities that contain a map with some property values:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @Lob
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "propname")
    @Column(name = "propvalue")
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    public TestEntity()
    {
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getProperties()
    {
        return this.properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties)
    {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

}
```

I want to query the propvalue of propname='b' where the propname='a' has propvalue='xyz'.

I am quite a beginner in JPA and I am completely irritated how to realize such a query.

Do you have any hints how to realize such a query?